# Can't assign actual value to jQuery UI Progress bar

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-progressbar

I have an issue with jQuery UI Progress bars. I got multiple progress bars on my page (for stacked progress bars indicating a multi-step progress) and I have the following code to initiate the progress bar and assign the value :

```
function createProgressBars(progressVal, progressValMax, callback) {

progressVal = $(this).data("progress-value");
progressValMax = $(this).data("progress-val-max");

$(".progress-bar").progressbar({
    value : progressVal,
    max : progressValMax
});

callback();}
jQuery(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".progress-bar").each(function(){
        var pv = $(this).data("progress-value"),
            pm = $(this).data("progress-max");

        createProgressBars(pv, pm);
    });
});
});
```

**EDIT : Added HTML Code**

```
<div class="progress-bar regular-user" data-progress-value="1000" data-progress-max="3000"></div>

<div class="progress-bar bronze-user" data-progress-value="500" data-progress-max="2000"></div>

<div class="progress-bar silver-user" data-progress-value="300" data-progress-max="2000"></div>

<div class="progress-bar gold-user" data-progress-value="200" data-progress-max="3000"></div>
```

But in the HTML attributes I have `aria-value-max=100` and `aria-value-now=0` .

How can I specify those values correctly? I had the same experience with a progress bar (a single one actually) and it worked fine.

Thanks guys.

Comment: show the html as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you do in `createPogressBar` is to overwrite the two parameters with `this` that does not point to anything at that point.
You could probably do:

```
jQuery(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".progress-bar").each(function(){
        var pv = $(this).data("progress-value"),
            pm = $(this).data("progress-max");

       $(this).progressbar({
          value : pv,
          max : pm
       });
    });
});
```

Or move the code to your `createProgressBar` function by sending only the `this` parameter.

```
function createProgressBars(container, callback) {

progressVal = $(container).data("progress-value");
progressValMax = $(container).data("progress-val-max");

$(container).progressbar({
    value : progressVal,
    max : progressValMax
});

callback();}
jQuery(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".progress-bar").each(function(){
        createProgressBars(this);
    });
});
```

EDIT:
I updated both codes. In the first case, we need to use `this` to create the right progress bar, not the general selector.

In the second case, we need to use the container.

Not doing so tries to re-generate all progress bars every time, which caused weird effects.

Comment: This code which is an edited version of mine, now has the problem of determining which `data-progress-value` and `data-progress-max` belongs to a certain element. It behaves oddly, I want every `data-*` attribute in every progress bar to affect that specific progress bar. Where's the problem? Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

you're setting pv and pm, passing this to the function, and then essentially recalculating those values inside the function. I think you should just get rid of these lines:

```
progressVal = $(this).data("progress-value");
progressValMax = $(this).data("progress-val-max");
```